# PHPUnit does not generate clover.xml report file

Tags: jenkins, phpunit, php-7, clover

These are my configs:

phpunit.xml

```
    <!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
    <phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
             backupGlobals="false"
             colors="true"
             bootstrap="../usr/core/autoload.test.php"
    >
        <php>
            <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
            <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="usr/core/" />
        </php>

        <testsuites>
            <testsuite name="Api">
                <directory>../usr/Project/Api/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </testsuite>
            <testsuite name="Backend">
                <directory>../usr/Project/Backend/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </testsuite>
            <testsuite name="CMS">
                <directory>../usr/Project/CMS/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </testsuite>
            <testsuite name="Console">
                <directory>../usr/Project/Console/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </testsuite>
            <testsuite name="Im">
                <directory>../usr/Project/Im/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </testsuite>
            <testsuite name="Library">
                <directory>../usr/Project/Library/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </testsuite>
            <testsuite name="Registration">
                <directory>../usr/Project/Registration/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </testsuite>
            <testsuite name="TestSuite">
                <directory>../usr/tests</directory>
            </testsuite>
        </testsuites>

        <filter>
            <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
                <directory>usr</directory>
                <exclude>
                    <directory>../usr/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                    <directory>../usr/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                    <directory>../usr/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                </exclude>
            </whitelist>
        </filter>
    </phpunit>
```

and ant configuration:

```
<target name="phpunit"
        unless="phpunit.done"
        description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
    <exec executable="${phpunit}" resultproperty="result.phpunit" taskname="phpunit">
        <arg value="--configuration"  path="${basedir}/build/phpunit.xml"/>
        <arg value="--coverage-clover"  path="${basedir}/build/logs/clover.xml"/>
        <arg value="--log-junit" path="${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.xml"/>
    </exec>

    <property name="phpunit.done" value="true"/>
</target>
```

so far everything works fine.
But when I execute in in jenkins I get the following message:

```
    Clover xml file does not exist in: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project5FullBuild called: build/logs/clover.xml and will not be copied to: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Project5FullBuild/builds/39/cloverphp/clover.xml
    Could not find 'build/coverage/build/logs/clover.xml'.  Did you generate the XML report for Clover?
```

I checked the logs directory.
No clover.xml existed.
I also already checked several other google hints, but nothing helped so far.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [whitelisting](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.whitelisting-files) in your config file does not yield files, phpunit will not generate a coverage xml file, to my knowledge.

Try modifying your filter element to make sure it includes files, e.g.:

> ```
> <filter>
>     <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
>         <directory suffix=".php">somedir</directory>
>     </whitelist>
> </filter>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, was necessary to install `php-xdebug` module, otherwise it did not work.